# Detect if output already sent in php

Tags: php, http-headers, gzip

I'm sending content to the browser via gzip if they support it (for css/js), currently I just use :

`stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') !== False`

However, if there was some output before then (ie. php error/warning), this breaks the gzip output and the browser (firefox at least) says the site is using an unsupported form of compression (because of the the prior output).

So, is there a way to detect if output was sent? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How do you do the gzip compression?

Comment: Current versions of PHP and `ob_gzhandler` check the Accept-Encoding: header themselves. The if test is redundant. You should however send a `header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");`

Comment: `ob_gzhandler` does also handle the case where some user agents mistakenly declare to accept gzip but they actually don’t support it properly.

Comment: @Gumbo http://pastebin.com/JeyCFYhA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`headers_sent()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) i believe.

Answer (score 1):

PHP provides the [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) function to serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the response of @prodigitalson, which is right, you can us the ob_* functions, ob_start, ob_start, etc. This will handle an Output Buffer (ob), and all the sent data is not really sent. An any time after the **ob_start** you can decide to flush (**ob_end_flush**) the buffer and it will be really sent, but you can as well use **ob_end_clean** to empty the buffer content. Check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

Output buffering can speed up outgoing communication of the response, and let you erase all the thing you've already responded, which is always a problem in PHP. Nice tool.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

[ob_start](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)() 
ob_flush()

to capture any output generated and either output it as a proper error message or ignore it.